# pushViewController does not work with TabbarController

Tags: iphone, ios, pushviewcontroller

I have a Tab Bar Controller app which using storyboard. Each tab has a UIWebview. I want to capture link when the user click the link on Webview if the link is an external link (if it is not my site) I want to open the link in a different UIViewControl. (like a popupi Twitter iphone app do that)

Right now; I got this code for capture the link (if the link is bing.com then it should open it another view controller) but I cannot open another UIViewController (in this case PopViewController). It gives me this error:

**No visible @interface for 'GundemViewController' declares the selector 'pushViewController:animated:'**

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

//CAPTURE USER LINK-CLICK.

NSURL *url = [request URL];

NSString *urlString = [url absoluteString];

/******
 UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked: When user click on a link in the app it senses the action
 */

if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {
    if ([urlString hasPrefix:@"http://www.bing.com/"]) {

        PopViewController *popUpView = [[PopViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PopupViewController" bundle:nil];

        [self pushViewController:popUpView animated:YES];
        return NO;
    }
}


return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can embed navigation controllers in each tab, so that instead of:

```
UITabBarController
    Tab1 View Controller
    Tab2 View Controller
    Tab3 View Controller
```

you have

```
UITabBarController
    Tab1 Navigation Controller
        Tab1 View Controller
    Tab2 Navigation Controller
        Tab2 View Controller
    Tab3 Navigation Controller
        Tab3 View Controller
```

and so on.  You can only call `-pushViewController:animated:` on an instance of a navigation controller.

In your app delegate, you probably initialize each of your view controllers, put them in an array, and then assign that array to the tab bar controller.  To add navigation controllers, you have an extra step:

```
UIViewController *tab1Controller = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibNamed:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *tab1Nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:tab1Controller];

// etc
```

Then set the array of view controllers for your tab bar controller to the navigation controllers you've created.

In your view controllers, rather than call `-pushViewController:animated:` on `self`, you'll call it on `self.navigationController`.

*edit:*

If you don't want a navigation controller, you can use

```
[self presentViewController:popUpView 
                   animated:YES 
                 completion:nil];
```

to present the pop up.  In the pop up, when the user touches the close button, use

```
[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

to dismiss it.

Comment: Basically I just drag and drop a Tabbarcontroller into the stage (storyboard) than I am trying to achive create a popup (seperate from the all current tabs and other things) I just want to create a top view controller and when the user click the close button. I need to dismiss

Comment: Seamus I got that any idea will be appreciated *** WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener: delegate: <NSInternalInconsistencyException> Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/Umut/Library/ab.app> (loaded)' with name 'PopupViewController'

Comment: Looks like you are attempting to load a nib called "PopupViewController" but it doesn't exist. Maybe it should be "PopViewController", since that's the class name.

Comment: Silly me! I got everthing checked twice but passed the simplest thing :) I am appreciate for your help and time. Thanks

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer if it was helpful!  Glad to be of assistance!

Answer (score 1):

What is `GundemViewController`? Look into why that is being returned from `self.navigationController` instead of `UINavigationController`. One way to do that is to set a breakpoint just before you push the view controller and then step into the `self.navigationController` call.

Comment: GundemViewController is an UIViewController. Could you please check that part again. I edited that part.

Comment: You can't call `-pushViewController:animated:` on just any old view controller. You need to call it on a `UINavigationController`. The easiest way to do this is to call `self.navigationController`, which will return the navigation controller that the view controller is currently in.

Comment: But when I am doing this self.navigationController nothing happens? That is the problem I am trying the solve. Do I miss something? a method or something?

Comment: Is this view controller inside of a navigation controller? Likely, `self.navigationController` is returning nil if nothing is happening. In Storyboard, Editor > Embed In > Navigation Controller.

Comment: interesting... It did not work. All I want create a popup (like a top view controller, When user click the close button, I need to dismiss the view and back to the my site) Like Twitter app, They do the same if you click an external link they navigate you in a different view.